# WPF Отследить сколько секунд мышь остается на Label

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, таймер

Не знаю как можно реализовать следующие: Когда мышь входит в область label(MouseEnter), если мышь остается в области label 3 секунды, то создается новый контрол. При этом надо сделать так чтобы главный поток не останавливался, а если таймер делать в другом потоке, то надо чтобы этот поток имел возможность создавать элементы на форме(в главном потоке). Если мышь выходит за пределы label и 3 секунды не прошло то ничего не создается соответственно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всё просто. При заходе мыши в лейбл, делаем 2 задачи: первая закончится через 3 секунды, вторая закончится когда мышь покинет лейбл.

Ждем конца любой из задач. После этого проверяем - если закончилась первая, то добавляем элемент, если вторая - то ничего не делаем.

Все это запускается асинхронно, никаких таймеров не надо.

Пример кода:

```
class Wnd : Window
{
    public Wnd()
    {
        var lbl = new Label() { Content = "I AM LABEL" };
        var sp = new StackPanel() {Orientation = Orientation.Vertical};     
        sp.Children.Add(lbl);

        lbl.MouseEnter += async (sender, args) => {         
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

            MouseEventHandler leave = null;
            leave = (sender2, args2) => {           
                lbl.MouseLeave-=leave;
                tcs.SetResult(0);
            };

            lbl.MouseLeave+=leave;

            var delayTask = Task.Delay(3000);
            await Task.WhenAny(tcs.Task, delayTask);

            if (delayTask.IsCompleted)          
                sp.Children.Add(new Label() {Content="3 sec passed!"});                 
        };  

        this.Content = sp;
    }
}
```

В действии:

[image: action]

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lbl.MouseLeave += (s, arg) => { _cts?.Cancel(); };
        lbl.MouseEnter += async (s, arg) =>
        {
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), _cts.Token);
                //Your action here
                Trace.WriteLine("3 secs passed");
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                //Ignore: leave before 3 sec
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: неплохая идея, позвольте только немного критики :) `_cts?.Cancel();` - ? здесь лишний, оно вроде никогда не будет `null`. Вообще не рекомендую делать `_cts ` полем, так как его после этого любой метод может вы звать сколько хочет раз.

Comment: после первого вызова `_cts?.Cancel();` токен отмены сбросится? Или все след задачи сразу будут отменены?

Comment: и, если можно, отформатируйте код и хотя бы какие то пояснения добавьте

Comment: но вцелом идея рабочая, вы можете просто переделать мой пример на токен отмены и вместо 2 задач проверять результат задачи ожидания - была ли она завершена или отменена

Comment: `_cts?.Cancel()` не сбросится. Но при новом входе ему задается новое значение (`_cts=new CancellationTokenSource();`)

Comment: а, да, теперь увидел :) Тяжко смотреть, отформатируйте пожалуйста код.